# JavaScript - How to create a prototype function to print text in selected element?

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

I have a shortcut function `id()` that returns an element just like normal `document.getElementById()` would. Now I would like to create a prototype function `print()` that would replace `innerHTML`. I've tested some things and I got to the code below. It doesn't work and I don't quite understand why... Can somebody help me fix the problem? Thanks...

```js
var id = function(item) {
 this.element = document.getElementById(item);
 return element;
}

id.prototype.print = function(value) {
 this.element.innerHTML = value;
}
document.body.onclick = function() {
  id('target').print('printed!');
}
```

```css
#target {
  background: #00000055;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="target">some text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is a limitation in javascript. Only modify your own prototypes. Never modify the prototypes of standard JavaScript objects.

Comment: Ok... So what's the solution then? i woud want to modify the prorotype of id() function... Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, I think you can because you assign the standard object to a new reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, you need to construct an object to use its prototype. However, `new id` all the time is tedious, so let's move the construction into the function itself:

```js
function id(item) {
  var obj = Object.create(id.prototype);
  obj.element = document.getElementById(item);
  return obj;
}

id.prototype.print = function(value) {
  this.element.innerHTML = value;
}

document.body.onclick = function() {
  id('target').print('printed!');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="target">some text</div>
</body>
```

Now, let's do a couple of improvements. Rename `id` to `$` for brevity, make it accept arbitrary selectors and rename `print` to `html`:

```js
function $(selector) {
  var obj = Object.create($.prototype)
  obj.element = document.querySelector(selector);
  return obj;
}

$.prototype.html = function(value) {
  this.element.innerHTML = value;
}

document.body.onclick = function() {
  $('#target').html('printed!');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="target">some text</div>
</body>
```

Congratulations, we've just invented jQuery! ;)

Comment: Well.. I'm working on a small script that returns the scroll percentage of the target element, but then I would have to do some stuff that would use `innerHTML` to display it on a page which... as you said is tedious. That's why I wanted to get into prototypes that would shorten my future code...

Comment: @Quiver: these are valid reasons, but still, have you considered just using jQuery instead of reinventing it? Would save you lots of time...

Comment: Well... I would not want a 100kB library just for a script that has 20 lines of code. Plus i'm not using JQuery.. My first rule is not to use any script that I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `new` when calling the constructor to create an instance of an `id`, and don't explicitly return anything from the constructor so that an instance is returned by default - then, you can use the associated prototype methods:

```js
var id = function(item) {
 this.element = document.getElementById(item);
}

id.prototype.print = function(value) {
 this.element.innerHTML = value;
}
document.body.onclick = function() {
  const myElm = new id('target');
  myElm.print('printed!');
}
```

```css
#target {
  background: #00000055;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="target">some text</div>
</body>
```

When you do

```
return element;
```

at the end of the constructor, that will result in the returned element being a *plain HTML element*, not an instance of `id` (and only instances of `id` have a `print` method).

If you *don't* want to use `new` when calling `id`, then have `id` itself create return an instance of something which has a `print` method (by calling `new` in `id`, and returning it):

```js
var id = function(item) {
  const instance = new MyElmClass(item);
  return instance;
}
var MyElmClass = function(item){
  this.element = document.getElementById(item);
};

MyElmClass.prototype.print = function(value) {
 this.element.innerHTML = value;
}
document.body.onclick = function() {
  const myElm = id('target');
  myElm.print('printed!');
}
```

```css
#target {
  background: #00000055;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="target">some text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes... But when I call the prototype function I want to call it exactly like this:
`id('some_id').print('text to print');`

Comment: You can call `new` inside `id` if you want, see edit

Answer (score 0):

Your close, just instantiate the object and no need to return.

```
var id = function(item) {
    this.element = document.getElementById(item);
}

id.prototype.print = function(value) {
    this.element.innerHTML = value;
}

var target = new id('target'); // <-- instantiate the object

document.body.onclick = function() {
  target.print('printed!');
}
```